# Pass element value dynamically using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a loop that display buttons with class name that has javascript on it. I need to pass the id of span that is clicked. My problem is because of the loop there, I can get the ID by its index but what I want to get is the id of the clicked button dynamically.

```
 while(...){
    <span class="id">'.$table["id"].'</span>
    <input type="button" class="edit"  value="Edit"/>
    }


$('.edit').on('click', function (e) {
    var x=document.getElementsByClassName("id")[0];
    var xx = x.innerHTML;

         $.fancybox({
             ...
         }
        });
});
```

Comment: As i can see button doesn't have an ID? You want span text value, i guess?  Also, you can easily access elements by jquery (no need for pure js), since you already use it.

Answer (score 1):

sounds like you want to use

var x= $(this).closest("span");

that should get you the span next to the button clicked.

Comment: It's value is only `[object Object]`

Comment: try to add add text() at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use just `$(this)`. within your click event? 
You don't need to do this:

```
var x=document.getElementsByClassName("id")[0];
```

just say

```
var x = $(this);
```

because you are already on your element there, when the click event happens.

Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would go with [data attributes](http://api.jquery.com/data/) for passing variables, so you can leave classes for css style purposes only. Also if you are already using jQuery why not going all the way with it?

```
while(...){
<span class="id" data-id="id">'.$table["id"].'</span>
<input type="button" class="edit"  value="Edit" data-target="id"/>
}


$('.edit').on('click', function (e) {
    var data = $(this).data('target'); // Get the data-target attribute
    var target = $('*[data-id='+data+']'); // Find the matching span
    var xx = target.html(); // Get HTML from Span

     $.fancybox({
         ...
     }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this one, but it still gets the first value, not the value of the clicked button...